# Default shell for cron issue

Tags: cron

I have some commands, they are working under bash, but not as cronjob. To see, what cause the problem, i'm saving the output in a file, here my example:

```
51  *  *   *   *    source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm >> stack.log 2>&1
```

The content of the log file is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

That means, cron is using `sh` insead of `bash`. I've tried to change it in the `/etc/crontab`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

But this doesn't work. I've looked in the `/etc/passwd` and here i see, that the daemon is using `sh` as default shell. Both `root` and `pi` have `bash` as default shell.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
pi:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/pi:/bin/bash
```

What should i do to change the default shell for cron? I wouldn't set `/bin/bash` for the daemon user in `/etc/passwd`...imho this is not a good idea.

**edit**:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Mar 30  2012 /bin/sh -> dash
```

here the content of the `/etc/crontab`:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Comment: Why do you want to `source` in crons environment? Simply running the `~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` doesn't work? And you _can_ have problems with using ~ in non-bash-environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So....i have two solutions for my problem:

1. Wrapper script over the bash command, which i'm calling at the moment as cronjob. The problem here - for every cronjob i need one wrapper, and this is not the best sollution for me.
2. I've tried to call a ruby script as cronjob. This doesnt work, so i thought, i  need to call 'rvm use 1.9.3' and for that i need first to call 'source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm'. And here was my mistake. In my bash instance i have path to ruby, but not as cron. After i fixed this, everything is working fine and i can execute my ruby scripts als cronjob.

Alex Chamberlain helped me a lot and give me the most important hint(s). Thanks a lot for the help!!!

Answer (score 4):

Most such cases (where script works in shell but not in cron) are because of environment variables that are different in script. In many case the problems is `PATH` variable. You could use full paths to all executables you are running in script or modify `PATH` in first line of your script.

To trace such issues, you could start from dumping environment variables aviable to your script by using `env` command, like this:
    /usr/bin/env >/tmp/env.txt

Comment: i don't have any environment variables in my script...and /bin/env doesn't exists.

Comment: No, you _always_ have some enviroment variables in each shell. One example is `PATH` which was already mentioned. Try `/usr/bin/env` instead. Or use `which env` to check what is your full path to `env` util.

Answer (score 4):

The shell used is [`dash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell); a POSIX-compliant shell, which is designed to be much smaller and more stable than `bash`.

One could argue that you should be writing `cron` jobs to be POSIX-compliant. Alternatively, try encapsulating your logic into a script and prepending the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Comment: why #!/usr/bin/env bash and not #!/bin/bash? what is the difference?

Comment: IMHO not a lot. Strictly speaking, it allows `bash` to be stored elsewhere. Who would do that, I don't know!

Comment: i've tried this also...i have an wrapper bash script, which call my command, but this also doesn't work. But i'm wandering, why the changes in the /etc/crontab doesn't make the swich to bash.

Comment: @cupakob Can you paste your entire `/etc/crontab` please?

Comment: you can find it in my post

Comment: I think the problem is `source` is a builtin, which doesn't make sense to run in its own right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6073/discussion-between-cupakob-and-alex-chamberlain)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that `sourcing` your script into `cron` is absolutely what you want to do and, more importantly, necessary? I think that it's almost always a bad idea.

Moreover, when you're editing `cron` (as well as other tools that can be possibly launched by other users and/or other shells), try to take a step-by-step approach. For example, you can test your environment with something like this:

```
42  *  *   *   *    bash -c "echo home---$HOME---"   >> /tmp/cron-temp.log 2>&1
42  *  *   *   *    bash -c "echo shell---$SHELL---" >> /tmp/cron-temp.log 2>&1
```

or even:

```
42  *  *   *   *    bash -c "export"                 >> /tmp/cron-temp.log 2>&1
```

So you can have proof of your environment, etc.

To answer your question, I wouldn't change the shell for `cron`. I'd simply tell it to call `bash` and then let `bash` call your scripts.

Comment: the $SHELL was still 'sh' notwithstanding i have changed it in the /etc/crontab

Comment: Yes, it's also the default in my `cron`. As I said, I wouldn't change it. Just call your script through `bash` with `bash -c "yourscript"` and everything should be fine (don't source your script, you probably don't need it!)

Comment: yes, this will work, but i want to know, why the default shell was not changed.