# Get Bash instead of /bin/sh in a VNC session started by cron

Tags: vnc, cron, bash

When I open a terminal (e.g. lxsession or xterm) in LXDE which is running in a VNC session the shell is

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

However, I want my default shell which is `/bin/bash` to use my .bashrc file.

How can I get it?

The problem seems related to the fact that I start VNC at boot time via my crontab entry

```
@reboot vncserver &
```

If I start another VNC session from a shell I have a Bash shell as expected in this VNC session. Of course at login via SSH I get a Bash, too.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -hl /bin/bash` to your question.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -hl /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 844K Oct 18  2014 /bin/bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the problem originates form *cron* using `/bin/sh` and not the users `SHELL` default. I found other people having the same problem at

- [Default shell for cron issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/2157/58211)
- [How to change cron shell (sh to bash)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94456/159562)

As a result `/bin/sh` is the default SHELL when VNC is started by cron.

My solution is to start my vncserver by cron through a script in which I export the SHELL variable first like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SHELL=/bin/bash
vncserver
```

This solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK the default login shell is used even in `lxterminal`.

You can check what your **default** is by looking at the `/etc/passwd` file for you user e.g. `cat /etc/passwd | grep pi` for most Pi users.

If you wish to change your login shell use the `chsh` command.

**NOTE** `/bin/sh` is a symlink to the default system shell; normally `/etc/dash` and **should not be changed**

Comment: My default shell is already /bin/bash. But when I open a terminal in a VNC session, I just get /bin/sh.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by adding following line in my `~/.vnc/xstartup` :

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```