# How to start a VNC session correctly on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, vnc, cron

I start my VNC server via a `@reboot vncserver &` entry in my user's crontab.

But this seems to cause some problems since the cron environment is restricted. For examples see:

- [Get Bash instead of /bin/sh in a VNC session started by cron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/60330/58211)
- [Shutdown and reboot buttons not working in VNC session started by cron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/64287/58211)

So I would like to know a better way for starting a VNC server for a user under his account.

Comment: you can try adding it to your systemd startup, see http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/tightvnc

Comment: But this seems to run vnc server as root. I want to run the vnc server for two different users under their accounts.

Comment: *"this seems to run vnc server as root"* -> No.  Look at line 8 of the startup config file given there and see `man systemd.exec`.

Comment: Alright. It is a fixed user for a service which needs to be installed by root. So this requires a vnc-user.service for every user. I hope that with the right ownership a user could also restart his vnc.service. I prefer a method which does not involve root (like crontab) more but maybe this provides an alternative solution if cron doesn't work.

Comment: This is the same issue as discussed in [your other question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/64287/65097); probably one of these questions should be made more general and the other deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In your crontab, run your login shell with the option that does full login processing and have it run `vncserver`, e.g.:

```
bash -l -c vncserver
```

This will ensure that a) your preferred shell is used, and b) `/etc/profile` and your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` are read.

Comment: I tried this already, but it doesn't seem to fix issues related to PAM or polkit or whatever the problem is.